# Create session with fixed username and password in aspnet core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am working on a project where there are two users, student and admin. For students I have used IdentityUser but for admin I want to sign in with fixed admin username and password, lets say username is **Admin** and password is **admin123**. I don't want to do any signup for the admin. For student sign in I have this method in controller-

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Signin(Login login)
    {

        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(login.LoginUserId, login.LoginUserPassword, login.RememberMe, false);

            if(result.Succeeded)
            {

                return RedirectToAction("index", "Student"); 
            }

            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt");
        }
        return View(login);
    }
```

What changes I should do for admin login if it is possible without sign up.

Comment: The signInManager gets the login from somewhere. Wherever it gets that login from, you create an admin account data store, update your data retrieval to join on the admin data so that you can check for admin logins.
Then you need to return whether the account is an admin account or not in the result object, you can then add an if statement to redirect to the appropriate area.
Finally, insert your admin logins into the table manually, or provide functionality to do it, up to you.

Comment: So I need to add admin data manually in my Signup table and then check data when admin is trying to login?

Comment: Sure, I'd create a separate table for admin logins personally but you can change your table. The thing you need to do is declare the type of account in your table, for example, add a field called 'AccountType' with a 'A' for admin and a 'U' for user, then you know what type of login it is. If you return that back to your method, you can then check the new field and appropriately redirect to the correct location.

Comment: When the admin login,you could judge like below:`if(login.username=="Admin "&&login.userpassword=="admin123"){...}`

Comment: @Rena I've tried this process from the Signin Controller that I've mentioned in the question. But when I try to login after submitting the information it shows an error related to IndentityUser as signin authenticate the data from sign up.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do this on database level. When you create project in AspNet with authentication it automatically adds some tables to your database.

You can find connection string in appsettings.json in the root folder of your app. I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management studio for this demonstration. So I have connected to my database and I see following tables

[image]

What you need to do here is sign up as regular user Admin / admin123 through your app and then change user role in your database.

1. From table dbo.AspNetUsers find id column for user Admin you created with regular sign up through your app.
2. Then in dbo.AspNetUserRoles find column id that matches Admin id column from dbo.AspNetUsers and change the RoleId column to 2 or 3. No 2 is Administrator and No 3 is SuperAdmin